# Issues with redirect from .html pages to wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

here is my issue:

I have a static html site and under blog I have wordpress installed. Now I added a new database and installed a second wordpress that works perfectly, but I want to 301 redirect old .html pages to new ones so I can keep the links and rankings, but every time I try to change the .htaccess file my wordpress totally crashes and I have to re-install.

I just want to redirect dozen .html pages to new wp versions, example, I want to redirect www.site.com/page.html to www.site.com/page/

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is to use the redirection plugin for wordpress.

We used it when we converted an old static site and it works well and tracks the number of hit's etc.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/

Comment: thanks, I tried the plugin but for some reason it won't work, but I found Wp htaccess Control plugin and it solved my problem :) Thanks for the idea